# How to highlight selected row of a gridpanel in Ext.net from c# code behind or javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, ext.net

I am doing an EXT.NET project I want to highlight the selected row of the gridpanel that I have in my code even from code behind which is c# or from javascript function it doesn't matter
Any Help?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
var getRowClass = function (record, index, rowParams, store) {
     if (record.get("test") === "test2") {
        return "my-highlighted-row";
     }
};
```

and then

```
<View>
    <ext:GridView runat="server">
      <GetRowClass Fn="getRowClass" />
    </ext:GridView>
</View>
```

refer [here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?21101-CLOSED-How-to-highlight-entire-row-in-this-grid-control-when-value-valueXYZ) for documentation